# Sequelize, convert entity to plain object

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm not very familiar with javascript, and stunning, because i can't add new property, to object, that fetched from database using ORM names Sequelize.js.

To avoid this, i use this hack:

```
db.Sensors.findAll({
    where: {
        nodeid: node.nodeid
    }
}).success(function (sensors) {
        var nodedata = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(node)); // this is my trick
        nodedata.sensors = sensors;
        nodesensors.push(nodedata);
        response.json(nodesensors);
});
```

So, what normally way to add new properties to object.

If it can help, i use sequelize-postgres version 2.0.x.

**upd. console.log(node):**

```
{ dataValues: 
   { nodeid: 'NodeId',
     name: 'NameHere',
     altname: 'Test9',
     longname: '',
     latitude: 30,
     longitude: -10,
     networkid: 'NetworkId',
     farmid: '5',
     lastheard: Mon Dec 09 2013 04:04:40 GMT+0300 (FET),
     id: 9,
     createdAt: Tue Dec 03 2013 01:29:09 GMT+0300 (FET),
     updatedAt: Sun Feb 23 2014 01:07:14 GMT+0300 (FET) },
  __options: 
   { timestamps: true,
     createdAt: 'createdAt',
     updatedAt: 'updatedAt',
     deletedAt: 'deletedAt',
     touchedAt: 'touchedAt',
     instanceMethods: {},
     classMethods: {},
     validate: {},
     freezeTableName: false,
     underscored: false,
     syncOnAssociation: true,
     paranoid: false,
     whereCollection: { farmid: 5, networkid: 'NetworkId' },
     schema: null,
     schemaDelimiter: '',
     language: 'en',
     defaultScope: null,
     scopes: null,
     hooks: { beforeCreate: [], afterCreate: [] },
     omitNull: false,
     hasPrimaryKeys: false },
  hasPrimaryKeys: false,
  selectedValues: 
   { nodeid: 'NodeId',
     name: 'NameHere',
     longname: '',
     latitude: 30,
     longitude: -110,
     networkid: 'NetworkId',
     farmid: '5',
     lastheard: Mon Dec 09 2013 04:04:40 GMT+0300 (FET),
     id: 9,
     createdAt: Tue Dec 03 2013 01:29:09 GMT+0300 (FET),
     updatedAt: Sun Feb 23 2014 01:07:14 GMT+0300 (FET),
     altname: 'Test9' },
  __eagerlyLoadedAssociations: [],
  isDirty: false,
  isNewRecord: false,
  daoFactoryName: 'Nodes',
  daoFactory: 
   { options: 
      { timestamps: true,
        createdAt: 'createdAt',
        updatedAt: 'updatedAt',
        deletedAt: 'deletedAt',
        touchedAt: 'touchedAt',
        instanceMethods: {},
        classMethods: {},
        validate: {},
        freezeTableName: false,
        underscored: false,
        syncOnAssociation: true,
        paranoid: false,
        whereCollection: [Object],
        schema: null,
        schemaDelimiter: '',
        language: 'en',
        defaultScope: null,
        scopes: null,
        hooks: [Object],
        omitNull: false,
        hasPrimaryKeys: false },
     name: 'Nodes',
     tableName: 'Nodes',
     rawAttributes: 
      { nodeid: [Object],
        name: [Object],
        altname: [Object],
        longname: [Object],
        latitude: [Object],
        longitude: [Object],
        networkid: [Object],
        farmid: [Object],
        lastheard: [Object],
        id: [Object],
        createdAt: [Object],
        updatedAt: [Object] },
     daoFactoryManager: { daos: [Object], sequelize: [Object] },
     associations: {},
     scopeObj: {},
     primaryKeys: {},
     primaryKeyCount: 0,
     hasPrimaryKeys: false,
     autoIncrementField: 'id',
     DAO: { [Function] super_: [Function] } } }
```

I think next, what you think will be: "Ok, that is easy, just add your property to dataValues."

```
node.selectedValues.sensors = sensors;
node.dataValues.sensors = sensors;
```

I add this lines, and this don't work

Answer (score 47, accepted):

If I get you right, you want to add the `sensors` collection to the `node`. If you have a mapping between both models you can either use the `include` functionality [explained here](http://sequelizejs.com/docs/latest/models#eager-loading) or the `values` getter defined on every instance. You can find the docs [for that here](http://sequelizejs.com/docs/latest/instances#block-4-line-2).

The latter can be used like this:

```
db.Sensors.findAll({
  where: {
    nodeid: node.nodeid
  }
}).success(function (sensors) {
  var nodedata = node.values;

  nodedata.sensors = sensors.map(function(sensor){ return sensor.values });
  // or
  nodedata.sensors = sensors.map(function(sensor){ return sensor.toJSON() });

  nodesensors.push(nodedata);
  response.json(nodesensors);
});
```

There is chance that `nodedata.sensors = sensors` could work as well.

Comment: Thank you, all i need: node.values :)

Answer (score 240):

you can use the query options `{raw: true}` to return the raw result. Your query should like follows:

```
db.Sensors.findAll({
  where: {
    nodeid: node.nodeid
  },
  raw: true,
})
```

also if you have associations with `include` that gets flattened. So, we can use another parameter `nest:true`

```js
db.Sensors.findAll({
  where: {
    nodeid: node.nodeid
  },
  raw: true,
  nest: true,
})
```

[image]

Comment: "raw: true" will somehow flattens array injected by associated models. The only work around I found so far is to configs = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(configs));

Comment: That's simple and better approach than accepted answer. thanks

Comment: @SoichiHayashi Actually, its the reverse when you think about it... ;) Without raw: true, Sequelize somehow unflattens the result into objects. The results from the sql query are already flattened. I've found it useful a few times to get a flat result... +1 for this answer.

Comment: @SoichiHayashi to get raw but nested result, you can use `nest: true` along with `raw: true`.

Comment: any idea how to pass the `raw:true` as a global setting, so there is no need to pass it to every query? Thanks

Comment: If you have array of association(such as hasMany), try [toJSON](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#instance-method-toJSON), it actually returns object instead of string.

Comment: Note that `raw: true` will also ignore any `virtual` columns

Answer (score 151):

For those coming across this question more recently, `.values` is deprecated as of Sequelize 3.0.0. Use `.get()` instead to get the plain javascript object. So the above code would change to:

```
var nodedata = node.get({ plain: true });
```

Sequelize [docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/instances/#values-of-an-instance) here

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong - but I don't think this will work with an array of rows? For example with .findAndcount you'd have to .map the result rows and return .get on each to get what you need.

Comment: Probably easier to just run JSON.stringify or res.json (if you're working within express).

Comment: @backdesk - haven't tried it on an array - but from the [docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/instances/#values-of-an-instance) it looks like it should return the same thing.

Comment: Using `.get()` won't convert included associations, use `.get({ plain: true })` instead. Thanks for mentioning the suggestion from the docs.

Comment: Also useful if you already performed the query and thus can't issue `raw: true`

Comment: Best answer so far.

Answer (score 60):

**Best and the simple way of doing is :**

Just use the default way from **[Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/model/#findalloptions-promisearrayinstance)**

```
db.Sensors.findAll({
    where: {
        nodeid: node.nodeid
    },
    raw : true // <----------- Magic is here
}).success(function (sensors) {
        console.log(sensors);
});
```

> Note : [options.raw]  :   Return raw result. See sequelize.query for more
>   information.

---

**For the nested result/if we have include model , In latest version of sequlize ,**

```
db.Sensors.findAll({
    where: {
        nodeid: node.nodeid
    },
    include : [
        { model : someModel }
    ]
    raw : true , // <----------- Magic is here
    nest : true // <----------- Magic is here
}).success(function (sensors) {
        console.log(sensors);
});
```

Comment: This answer very useful, use native functionality provided by sequleize, in my case when i send more than one row in socket, stack overflow error happened.

Comment: If you have an array of child data, you will get wrong results. So, if posted query returns only one `sensors` with an array of child `someModel`, you will get an `array` of `sensors` with one `someModel` in each.

Comment: `raw` result also omits all `VIRTUAL` property values.

Answer (score 34):

As CharlesA notes in his answer, `.values()` is [technically deprecated](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/3218), though this fact isn't explicitly noted in the [docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/instances/#values-of-an-instance).  If you don't want to use `{ raw: true }` in the query, the preferred approach is to call `.get()` on the results.

`.get()`, however, is a method of an instance, not of an array. As noted in the linked issue above, Sequelize returns native arrays of instance objects (and the maintainers don't plan on changing that), so you have to iterate through the array yourself:

```
db.Sensors.findAll({
    where: {
        nodeid: node.nodeid
    }
}).success((sensors) => {
    const nodeData = sensors.map((node) => node.get({ plain: true }));
});
```

Comment: This worked for me! Though I don't know if 'get' is a JavaScript or a Sequelize function. Please enlighten me. Thanks

Comment: @antew It's a method on an object returned from the database - it's part of the sequelize library, not a native javascript function.

Comment: Took me ages to get to this working! Thank you. Was so difficult because I have a lot of nested includes, which is also a bug. So I have to do multiple queries, and I couldn't because of this!!!

Answer (score 23):

you can use map function. this is worked for me.

```
db.Sensors
    .findAll({
        where: { nodeid: node.nodeid }
     })
    .map(el => el.get({ plain: true }))
    .then((rows)=>{
        response.json( rows )
     });
```

Comment: Thanks this was the best solution for my use cast, just `results = results.map(el => el.get({ plain: true }))`

Comment: I was searching for `get({ plain: true })`. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

Here's what I'm using to get plain response object with non-stringified values and all nested associations from `sequelize` v4 query.

With **plain JavaScript** (ES2015+):

```
const toPlain = response => {
  const flattenDataValues = ({ dataValues }) => {
    const flattenedObject = {};

    Object.keys(dataValues).forEach(key => {
      const dataValue = dataValues[key];

      if (
        Array.isArray(dataValue) &&
        dataValue[0] &&
        dataValue[0].dataValues &&
        typeof dataValue[0].dataValues === 'object'
      ) {
        flattenedObject[key] = dataValues[key].map(flattenDataValues);
      } else if (dataValue && dataValue.dataValues && typeof dataValue.dataValues === 'object') {
        flattenedObject[key] = flattenDataValues(dataValues[key]);
      } else {
        flattenedObject[key] = dataValues[key];
      }
    });

    return flattenedObject;
  };

  return Array.isArray(response) ? response.map(flattenDataValues) : flattenDataValues(response);
};
```

With **lodash** (a bit more concise):

```
const toPlain = response => {
  const flattenDataValues = ({ dataValues }) =>
    _.mapValues(dataValues, value => (
      _.isArray(value) && _.isObject(value[0]) && _.isObject(value[0].dataValues)
        ? _.map(value, flattenDataValues)
        : _.isObject(value) && _.isObject(value.dataValues)
          ? flattenDataValues(value)
          : value
    ));

  return _.isArray(response) ? _.map(response, flattenDataValues) : flattenDataValues(response);
};
```

**Usage**:

```
const res = await User.findAll({
  include: [{
    model: Company,
    as: 'companies',
    include: [{
      model: Member,
      as: 'member',
    }],
  }],
});

const plain = toPlain(res);

// 'plain' now contains simple db object without any getters/setters with following structure:
// [{
//   id: 123,
//   name: 'John',
//   companies: [{
//     id: 234,
//     name: 'Google',
//     members: [{
//       id: 345,
//       name: 'Paul',
//     }]
//   }]
// }]
```

Comment: Thanks! The toPlain works as expected and solved my issue as well.

Comment: This is neat, but it's no good if you override any of your model's toJSON methods. I do this quite a lot to either remove or convert the createdAt/updatedAt values. So far the only thing that has worked properly for me is JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response)).

Comment: Your answer gave me a nudge to look deeper into [Model](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js~Model.html)'s doc and [toJSON](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/65549922fbe3a823cd11b3e8eea64122fe6142a5/src/model.js#L4651). After fixing a custom getter in my model definition, `toJSON` worked well for me, so had no need for a custom implementation like yours.

Comment: I believe this is the only working solution. ```get({plain:true})``` adds all non requested fields with undefined. ```{raw:true, nest:true}``` does not deal with 1:n nested associations well.

Answer (score 10):

I have found a solution that works fine for nested model and array using native JavaScript functions.

```
var results = [{},{},...]; //your result data returned from sequelize query
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(results); //convert to string to remove the sequelize specific meta data

var obj = JSON.parse(jsonString); //to make plain json
// do whatever you want to do with obj as plain json
```

Comment: So simple, yet powerfully works and keeps the model logic. I don't know how efficient it is, but it was good enough for me.

You can short it to something like:
let res = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));

Answer (score 7):

For plain objects

```
db.model.findAll({
  raw : true ,
  nest : true
})
```

Comment: it doesn't work propery for one to many association its better to use  .map(obj => obj.get({ plain: true }))

Comment: actually i am talking about db.model.findOne and one to many association.

Comment: watch out, that doesn't give you json. it gives you plain objects.

Comment: brother it remove one to many relation

Comment: it is invalid when we use associate concept

Answer (score 2):

You can also try this if you want to occur for all the queries:

```
var sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'username', 'password', {query:{raw:true}})
```

Visit [Setting all queries to raw = true sequelize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26228499/setting-all-queries-to-raw-true-sequelize)

Comment: So - how does this work when you are doing an upsert?!

Answer (score 2):

It's a little late to answer, but in case someone runs across this question and needs a solution...

**(Assuming this is in async/await function)**

```
const sensors = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(await 
    db.Sensors.findAll({
    where: {
        nodeid: node.nodeid
    }
})))
```

You can query and return it is a plain object, array of objects, etc...

Comment: this answer is working for association also .. plus 1 added

Answer (score 2):

I use my own model mixin for handy responses

```
const camelcaseKeys = require('camelcase-keys');

const initMixins = Sequelize => {
    // Convert model to plain object and camelcase keys for response
    Sequelize.Model.prototype.toPlainObject = function({ camelcase = false } = {}) {
        const plain = this.get({ plain: true });
        if (camelcase) {
            return camelcaseKeys(plain, { deep: true });
        } else {
            return plain;
        }
    };
};

module.exports = {
    initMixins,
};
// usage
const userModel = await UserModel.findOne();
console.log(userModel.toPlainObject());
```