# Get only dataValues from Sequelize ORM

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I'm using the sequelize ORM to fetch data from a PSQL DB. However, when I retrieve something, a whole bunch of data is given. The only data I want is inside 'dataValues'. Of course, I can use object.dataValues. But, is there any other good solutions?

I'm using Sequelize 4.10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem occurs only when I log it using:

> console.log(Model.findAll());

If I save it to a variable, I can directly access objects inside without using "**dataValues**"

Comment: This works on JS, but on typescript, the following error will trigger: "error TS2551: Property 'dataValues' does not exist on type 'Model'. Did you mean 'getDataValue'?" For this cases Masoud Tavakkoli answer solve the problem.

Answer (score 151):

Yes you can

```
Model.findAll({
 raw: true,
 //Other parameters
});
```

would return just the data and not the model instance

Comment: Can I apply that to all queries globally?

Comment: You can define it while creating the connection. Something like 
`const sequelize = new Sequelize('connectionUri', {
  define: {
    raw: true 
  }
});`.
From the docs [here](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/installation/getting-started.html#application-wide-model-options)

Comment: Please not this does not work with eager loading nested entities.

Comment: To apply to all queries, use `var sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'username', 'password', {query:{raw:true}})` as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/26228558/1802726.

Comment: While i'm writing this comment this answer has 55 upvotes, then why it is in last thread ?, it must be on top list. I think Stack Overflow need to change it's algorithm.

Comment: You should have some disclaimer while picking raw

Answer (score 53):

Sequelize wraps all it's return values in a virtual object that contains meta data. If you have an object and you just want the undecorated data values, you can unwrap them like so:

```
Model.findById(1).then(data => {
  console.log(data.get({ plain: true }));
});
```

Additionally if you just want to print out the object you can use the `.toJSON` method.

```
Model.findById(1).then(data => {
  console.log(data.toJSON());
});
```

Comment: I like the `data.get` answer you gave, it's almost exactly what I want. But do you know if there's a way that one could specify the `data.get` (or the `plain:true`, or anything else, really) part in the `find`'s options? E.g. instead of doing what you did, rather something like `Model.findOne({ plain:true, ... }).then(...)` ? Because the way I see it, if you're only going to filter out the data you want *inside* the `.then()`, you might as well save yourself some time and just do `data.dataValues` instead of `data.get(...)`.

Comment: @PrintlnParams See Shivam's answer for details on that, if you want to do that globally see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/26228558/3803506
  

The method I described is more if you want to use the object for instance methods, etc but you want to encapsulate the implementation details before passing on the values, or for logging. `data.dataValues` works as well but be careful of mutability, also keep in mind that `dataValues` is sequelize's internal implementation which may change.

Answer (score 20):

Finally I found answer after searching a lot. you should do something like this

```
const users = await db.users.findAll({})
   .map(el => el.get({ plain: true })) // add this line to code
```

source: [github issue](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/6950#issuecomment-373937803)

Answer (score 8):

This is how I solved mine

```
    let rows = await database.Book.findAll(options);
    rows = JSON.stringify(rows);
    rows = JSON.parse(rows);
```

Note that the query has 'include childModel' i could've used 'raw:true' if it just one model. Stringifying the result clears out the '_previousDataValues' e.t.c and give you plain object, now parse the stringified obect back to json. Took me a long time before I could figure this out.

Answer (score 7):

To clarify Masoud Tavakkoli's answer (which is not immediately clear on that github answer): using `element.get({ plain: true })` returns an array of **objects** with each attribute key:value pairs.

If you just want an array of one specific attribute's values (eg user ids) instead of objects, you can use something like this:

```
const users = await User.findAll({
    attributes: ["id"], 
    where: {} // Your filters here
}).map(u => u.get("id")) // [1,2,3]
```

Nika Kasradze's answer actually achieves the same outcome as a middle-step; using the JSON stringifier generates the same array output. It's possible this is faster than mapping, but I'm not sure.

```
const users = await User.findAll({
    attributes: ["id"], 
    where: {} // Your filters here
})
const userIds = JSON.stringify(users)) // [1,2,3]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to change your finder methods (e.g., some consumers may want the Mongo object and some just the data), you can use `.toJSON` to get the object from the former.

```
const query = await myQuery(id);
const record = query.toJSON();
```