# Sequelize findOne returned instance. Row is in dataValues, but direct properties on instance are undefined

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

**Context**: I'm testing a simple model into and out of the database. Not a real test, it's a precursor to some integration tests. Using **Sequelize** and **`findOne`**.

**The problem**: The direct data on the returned model instance, i.e. email.ulid, email.address, email.isVerified are undefined.

**My question**: Why are they undefined?

```
Sequelize: 5.15.0
Typescript: 3.5.3
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.4.6-MariaDB
```

*Record into database*:

```
await testingDatabase.sync({
  force: true
}).then(async () => {
  await Email.create({
    ulid: the_ulid.bytes,
    address: "dave@world.com",
    isVerified: false
  })
})
```

*Fetch the record back:*

```
await Email.findOne({
  where: { 
    address: "dave@world.com"
  }
  , rejectOnEmpty: true //to shut typescript up
}).then( emailData => {
   console.log("Email: ", email)
})
```

*Console.log* of `email` instance:

```
    Email:  Email {                                                                                                                                                      
      dataValues: {                                                                                                                                                      
        ulid: <Buffer 01 6c a3 36 11 9c 1e 9b a6 ce 60 b7 33 3e e7 21>,                                                                                                  
        address: 'dave@world.com',                                                                                                                                    
        isVerified: false,                                                                                                                                               
        deletedAt: null,                                                                                                                                                 
        createdAt: 2019-08-18T05:32:05.000Z,                                                                                                                             
        updatedAt: 2019-08-18T05:32:05.000Z                                                                                                                              
      },                                                                                                                                                                 
      ...,
      isNewRecord: false,
      ulid: undefined,
      address: undefined,
      isVerified: undefined,
      createdAt: undefined,
      updatedAt: undefined,
      deletedAt: undefined
    }
```

^^^ As is clear, immediately above, all of the direct attributes on the instance are null.

**The following works**, but with the side-effect that `isVerified` is returned as a `0` rather than `false` and subsequently fails a direct comparison with the original data. Additionally, I lose other functionality of the model instance that will come in handy on more complex models:

```
Email.findOne({
  where: { address: "dave@world.com" }
, raw: true 
, rejectOnEmpty: true
})
```

**These also work**, but with the consequence that Typescript complains about the returned object not having the properties I then access (although they do exist and the test works):

```
.then( emailData => {
  console.log("All getters: ", emailData.get())
  // AND
  console.log("All getters(plain): ", emailData.get({plain: true}))
  // AND
  console.log("toJSON: ", emailData.toJSON())
})
```

**This next one (suggested by Vivek)**, works insofar as the data is available, but JSON.parse fails to handle the Buffer properly:

```
const dataOnly = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(emailData))
```

Others have complained ([SE answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46537972/5057805)) that console.log somehow misprints the instance, yet every other way I access these properties they are still undefined.

Comment: I also tried `mapToModel` with `instance` set, in the hope that it would stimulate the model to populate. It did not.

Comment: Watching https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/10917, although this merely addresses the side-effects of some of the workarounds found so far, not the actual question of "why are they undefined".

Comment: Exact same issue [11326](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/11326) as this question exists on sequelize github.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution:**

The problem was with a `Babel` plugin.

Setting up Sequelize models as per the Sequelize/Typescript [documentation](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/typescript.html), defines class properties on each model representing model fields.

The babel plugin:

```
"@babel/proposal-class-properties"
```

within:

```
plugins: [
  "@babel/proposal-class-properties"
, ...
]
```

Transforms these class properties into `defineProperty()` calls on the model Class object, called in turn by the helper `_defineProperty()`:

```
  _defineProperty(this, "yourFieldName", void 0);
```

This initializes the property on the object with the value `undefined`.

Evidently, when `findOne` subsequently tried to update the model, it refused to overwrite these existing properties on the model.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to investigate and answer your own question here to help others :)

Comment: Agreed, thanks for pointing me in the right direction to solving this.  Configuring the plugin to exclude my models folder fixed this for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61960885/how-to-make-typescript-transpile-my-sequelize-model

Comment: Sorry, but I am unable to figure out what the _solution_ is. What is the solution?

Comment: @pihentagy it's been a while, but I believe I removed the plugin above.

Answer (score 6):

I hit the same issue but in a slightly different context.

My solution was **not** to use the `ESNext` target in my tsconfig.json. Using `ES2021` or any other target solved the problem.

Comment: This should be the accepted solution, as of Sept 2021. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, you can try out simply `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify`;

```
Email.findOne({
  where: { 
    address: "dave@world.com"
  }
}).then( emailData => {
   const dataOnly = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(emailData));
   console.log(dataOnly); // <--- YOUR DATA
   console.log(emailData); // <--- YOUR INSTANCE
})
```

---

> "Typescript complains about the returned object not having the
>   properties I then access"

```
.then( emailData => {
  console.log("All getters: ", emailData.get())
  // AND
  console.log("All getters(plain): ", emailData.get({plain: true}))
  return emailData.get({plain: true}); // <-- I think you forgot to return this
});
```

I think that error is because you might not be returning the result back. Check the above code.

Comment: That's a serviceable attempt, thanks. But unfortunately it falls into the growing list of not-quite-right solutions. JSON.parse doesn't handle the Buffer gracefully, instead it names the type and gives an array of decimal numbers.

Comment: @PaulParker, where did you get this error : " but with the consequence that Typescript complains about the returned object not having the properties I then access"

Comment: This is a typescript error. I can ignore it and the program still functions properly, it just clutters up my editor. I use `@babel/preset-typescript`, which discards typescript on compile, rather than trying to handle typescript errors. This allows production to continue, even in the face of an intractable Typescript problem.

Comment: Check the updated answer that might solve your error and for you `emailData.get({plain: true})` is the perfect solution. @PaulParker

Comment: I am returning it. The Typescript error arises because I try to delete fields from the data, and Typescript doesn't know of the existence of those fields. Both `.get()` and `.toJSON()` are not giving TS any type information.

Comment: @PaulParker, in that case, you can ignore that error as its just affecting editors