# How to include model in sequelize without nesting the output

Tags: postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I have the following code

```
    Locations.findAll({
    attributes: ['id', 'location_name'],
    include: [{
        model: Somemodel,
        attributes: ['hierarchy_name']
       }]
    })
```

This will provide an output like this:

```
    id: 1
    location_name: "City"
    parent_id: 0
    hierarchy: 1
    location_hierarchy: {hierarchy_name: "Division"}
```

Is there any way that i can get the **hierarchy_name** without nesting the output with sequelize? Like this:

```
    id: 1
    location_name: "City"
    parent_id: 0
    hierarchy: 1
    hierarchy_name: "Division"
```

I know that i can destructure the data before sending it to client and i will get the format i want. But i want to know if this can be done directly from sequelize.

Answer (score 0):

If you are expecting a massive dataset that you just want to display, without manipulation then you need to set an option `raw` to `true`.

Please refer the following question -

[Setting all queries to raw = true sequelize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26228499/setting-all-queries-to-raw-true-sequelize)

I hope it helps!